# Strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following function

```
export const startAddExpense = (expenseData = {}) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const uid = getState().auth.uid;
    const {
      description = '',
      note = '',
      amount = 0,
      createdAt = 0
    } = expenseData;
    const expense = { description, note, amount, createdAt };

    return database.ref(`users/${uid}/expenses`).push(expense).then((ref) => {
      dispatch(addExpense({
        id: ref.key,
        ...expense
      }));
    });
  };
};
```

I get this error

```
Uncaught Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "users/+ uid +[object Object]/expenses". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
```

in this line

```
return database.ref(`users/${uid}/expenses`).push(...)
```

How can I fix that error?
Thanks,
Theo

Comment: What is the value of `uid` set here `const uid = getState().auth.uid;`?

Comment: @radovix This one 0WjrPi8sKeR4NHWLGnkdJnqbyT03

Comment: your uid seems to be an object..check u chk again... because `0WjrPi8sKeR4NHWLGnkdJnqbyT03` shd work just fine ....

Comment: looks like an unclosed quote wherever you're setting uid.  somewhere you're probably doing something like setState({auth:{uid:"string1+ uid +",obj...})